# GIT remote cannot fetch via SSH

Tags: git, ssh, repository, fetch

I've just initialized a GIT repo in an existing website root.
I have a local development copy of this site, which is already a GIT repo. I can't just clone one from the other, as the local/live versions have fallen out of sync over the years.

I'm trying to get them lined back up with GIT again, but I want to be able to do a **fetch** on the live site and run **git diff**

My problem is, on the local site I've added the live site as a remote repo:

```
git remote add live user@server.co.uk:/path/to/repo
```

I can successfully log in via ssh to my server:

```
ssh user@server.co.uk
```

But when I try to fetch, and type in the ssh password, the command line just returns the password prompt, as if I've typed it wrong. But I know the password is correct, as I can use SSH to log in.

Do I have to specify **ssh://** before my remote URL? Is there something I have to do to get ssh remote repos working

**UPDATE**

I've added the **ssh://** prefix, but it's made no difference. This is how it looks in .git/config

```
[remote "live"]
    url = ssh://user@server.co.uk/path/to/repo
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/live/*
```

Running **GIT_TRACE=true git fetch live** adds in the lines:

```
trace: run_command 'ssh' 'user@server.co.uk' 'git-upload-pack '\''/path/to/repo'\'''
```

I have to type the password in 3 times before I get the message:

```
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: did you initialized with '--bare' option?

Comment: On the live site, no. Not sure what the difference is between "git init" and "git init --bare"

Comment: as @tigran said, you need to build a repo on the live server with `--bare` flag. about the difference, you can read it from here: http://progit.org/book/ch4-2.html

Comment: The website is live though, I'm turning an existing set of files into a repository. Doesn't that mean the working directory isn't empty? Or the site root is the working directory?

Comment: I assume the ssh user has full permissions on the server-side repo, path and files?

Comment: Just to check the really obvious thing - ISTR some versions of git make multiple SSH connections on `git fetch`, so if you just keep typing in the password when prompted, does it complete successfully?

Comment: And also, please add to your question the output from `GIT_TRACE=true git fetch`

Comment: Why the `ssl` tag? SSH has nothing to do with SSL.

Comment: Did I put SSL? Sorry, didn't mean to, I've been doing some SSL/Https stuff this morning, got my wires crossed.

Comment: The user has full permissions, I can ssh in and make directories and files etc, and I haven't tried putting the password in multiple times. I got to 3 just thinking I was typing it wrong, would git need that many connections?

Comment: Right, if I type in the password 3 times, I then get the "fatal: remote end hung up unexpectedly" message.

Comment: I created a second bare repo, and successfully pushed that to the remote server. I think my problem is related to the fact I'm trying to convert an already quite large website into a working directory, which I can then push changes to from my local server.

Comment: I've updated my answer below. I think you might be missing a colon in the remote url.

Comment: I created a --bare clone next to my live site. I can fetch from that fine, and I'll use that with a post-recieve hook to update the actual web root. Which is better for me anyway, but that doesn't explain why I couldn't pull from the existing repo, the webroot

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing an alias for the remote.

```
git remote add origin user@server.co.uk:/path/to/repo
```

Note the `origin` bit.

Is the .git/config you posted accurate? If it is, try changing the remote url from

`url = ssh://user@server.co.uk/path/to/repo`

to

`url = user@server.co.uk:/path/to/repo`

Note the `:` separating the server name from the server path.

Comment: I've got "live" as the alias, I've updated my question to show the config file.

Comment: Adding the : gives me "ssh: Could not resolve hostname server.co.uk:: Name or service not known
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Comment: OK, I can reproduce your error now actually, which is encouraging. I can reproduce it with a url like `ssh://user@server.co.uk:/path/to/repo` but not with a url like `user@server.co.uk:/path/to/repo`. I have again amended the answer above. Try with a url string in `.git/config` like `user@server.co.uk:/path/to/repo`. To be clear, the ssh:// part is dropped and the colon separating the server from the path is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need ssh://. Just change it in .git/config file:

```
url = ssh://user@server.co.uk:/path/to/repo
```

Comment: I have the same setup and I don't need the ssh:// prefix. Can you elaborate on why he needs it?

Comment: Tried it with and without, gives the same response, just keeps asking for the password

Comment: try to run git on remote host: ssh user@server.co.uk "git --version"

Comment: ssh user@server.co.uk "git --version" works fine, returns "git version 1.7.4.1"

Answer (score 0):

Following only applys if you have shell access to the server. Probably not what you want but incase you want to try set up a public/private key auth. Simply generate a RSA keypair with command :

`ssh-keygen -t rsa` 
I would reccomend you to use a passphrase since you can store it in `ssh-agent` after generating a keypair copy the public key over to your server you can use scp :

`scp -p ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub host:~/.ssh/` and then in server do `cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys`

Comment: I did wonder if GIT just doens't work without SSH keypairs, but ssh user@server.co.uk "git --version" seems to work ok without. I might give this a try though

Comment: Git does work without keypairs but I always set it up using SSH keypairs it just makes my life 10 times easier.